# Bitbucket Cloud webhook to trigger branch specific Cloud Build URL

Tags: git, google-cloud-build, bitbucket-cloud

We building a CI/CD based on BitBucket and Google Cloud Build.
We have one Cloud Build trigger per project: dev, staging, prod

How can we configure one or 3 webhook that based on the branch will trigger the specific Cloud Build?
The only "workaround" we found is to have a Cloud Function which receives BitBucket trigger POST message and based on the JSON "name" field, triggers the specific Cloud Build. Is it the best way to move ahead?

Thanks

Comment: As stated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/bitbucket/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud#creating_webhook_triggers) Create triggers for each environment from the cloud build console and  push to specific branch in your bitbucket repository.

Comment: thanks, based on the documented shred, I created for each trigger a substitution that gets the "_BRANCH" name and a filter that only triggers when the branch is in sync with the project. working now!
One basic question ... cloudbuild.yaml file inside the repo to do the build, but if I change it, it doesn't take the last changed file. It uses the previous file release ... how to make it assume the new changed file?

Comment: found how to force "cloudbuild.yaml" update ... It seems GCP copies BitBucket repo to Google Cloud Souce Repository and uses it to read the "cloudbuild.yaml" file (not getting it from BitBucket directly). So, to update the repo copy in GCP, you need to go to "Cloud Source Repositories" and force "Sync from BitBucket". Not sure if there is an "easy" and "straightforward" way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Cloud Build now supports Bitbucket natively, see https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/release-notes#March_07_2024

There are basically two approaches you can follow with Cloud Build alone, and more if you use a Cloud Function (or other) as an intermediate layer. Sathi Aiswarya pointed to the [relevant document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/bitbucket/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud#creating_webhook_triggers) in his note.

1. With 3 triggers (as you have), you'll need 3 webhooks, one for each trigger, and you can use a filter (as documented) to decide whether the trigger should fire based on the webhook payload.
2. You could have a single trigger instead, which runs a build that inspects the payload to decide which build to run. You can either do this within your build script/steps, or as a standalone build that then triggers the build you really want to run. The latter is essentially the same approach as using a Cloud Function. Either way, you'll need to define [substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) to pass what you need from the payload to the build.

Comment: Thanks! Used the option 1, working now with "Subsitutions" to get JSON from BitBucket post and Filter to match the right name!